# How can I resolve a service through a delegate factory with a conditional decorator?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a class hirerachy that looks like this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
        => _bar = bar;
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    private readonly Func<IFoo> _fooFunc;
    private readonly IBaz _baz;

    public Bar(Func<IFoo> fooFunc, IBaz baz)
    {
         _fooFunc = fooFunc;
         _baz = baz;
    }
}

public class Baz : IBaz
{
}

public class BazDecorator : IBaz
{
    private readonly IBaz _decoratee;

    public BarDecorator(IBaz decoratee)
        => _decoratee = decoratee;
}
```

Note that `Bar` takes `Func<IFoo>` instead of `IFoo` directly because of the circular dependency when resolving for `IFoo`.

My current registration looks likes this:

```
public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>();

        builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<IBar>();

        // Func<IFoo> is automatically resolved in AutoFac

        builder.RegisterType<Baz>().Named<IBaz>("baz");

        builder.RegisterDecorator<IBaz>((c, inner) =>
            new BazDecorator(inner),
            fromKey: "baz");
    }
}
```

I would like to conditionally register `BazDecorator` only when resolving through `Foo` *but not* `Func<IFoo>` like:

```
Foo------Bar-----BazDecorator----Baz
          \
           \
            \____Foo----Bar----Baz
```

How can I register my services in AutoFac?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your `Func<IFoo>` manually, to pass proper parameters explicitly to the `Foo` and `Bar` components

```
builder.Register<Func<IFoo>>(c =>
    {
        var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return () => new Foo(new Bar(() => ctx.Resolve<IFoo>(), ctx.ResolveNamed<IBaz>("baz")));
    });
```

If you do not want to "new" `Foo` and `Bar` inside `Register` function, it could also be achieved by resolving them from the container, but the code looks quite nasty:

```
builder.Register<Func<IFoo>>(c =>
    {
        var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return () => ctx.Resolve<IFoo>(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, cx) => p.Name == "bar", 
                (p, cx) => cx.Resolve<IBar>(new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p1, c1) => p1.Name == "baz", 
                    (p1, c1) => c1.ResolveNamed<IBaz>("baz")))));
    });
```

Comment: Can this be avoided? Since in my actual code, `Baz` and `BazDecorator` are actually very deep in the object graph so I would like to avoid explicitly registering a huge portion of my object graph if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot think of any other solution with would require less code or changing your original code...